# Ec2 Refuses to Allow me To Login via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've been using Amazon EC2 Instance up to this point running ubuntu primarily with django/python configurations, but i wanted to use a LAMP ami this time (with the same exact security group) , and it refuses to allow me to login:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
new-host:~ user$ ssh -v -i ThrowAwayEC2Server.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ThrowAwayEC2Server.pem type -1
debug1: identity file ThrowAwayEC2Server.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA e7:ef:60:19:a8:cf:e6:04:9a:9c:f9:a7:b2:12:a5:4b
debug1: Host 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:21
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: ThrowAwayEC2Server.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Anyone know why this isn't working? I've tried:

- different ami's (lamp based, some bitnami)
- using totally new .pem files

Can anyone help? Anything you see wrong that is happening?

Thanks!

different ami

Comment: Possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457695/unable-to-ssh-to-amazon-ec2-account-public-key-error

Comment: This isnt a duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a problem so much with the syntax of the connection string, but a *username* error.

If you are attempting to connect to a *bitnami*, community-driven ami - the username is bitnami, so for example:

```
ssh -i yourkeyfile.pem bitnami@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```